# JavaFX изменить Text вне контроллера

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Я новичок, совсем, поэтому мне пожалуйста как нубу.

Есть GUI созданный через Scene Builder. Одна из кнопок GUI запускает новый Thread со своей реализацией в другом классе, который в последующем должен менять значение в самом GUI(Text в основном) на новые значения.

Если сделать в контроллере кнопку UPDATE к примеру, и приписать ей setText какого нибудь text, все конечно будет работать. Но это не наш случай.

---

Вопрос 1.
Если сделать костыль ради эксперимента в виде public static(в контроллере к переменной Text) и попытаться setText из нового потока в другом классе - не работает, во всяком случае в GUI Нового значения не отображается. А надо чтобы отображались новые значения.

Вопрос 2.
Я понимаю что использовать public static Text(в контроллере) в данном случае является ошибкой. В таком случае как правильно обращаться к контроллеру(и нужно ли вообще?) чтобы изменять те или иные значения, или обращаться к функциям?

Вообще знает кто нибудь что почитать на русском по Scene builder + javaFX или может авторов на ютубе каких нибудь?

Comment: Если делать по первому способу через костыли, то в статик переменную надо сохранять не какое-то поле, а экземпляр контроллера, который можно получить либо из самого контроллера controller = this, либо его можно запросить после вызова fxmlloader.load()

Comment: А как правильно делать? Т.е. если через костыли то private static Text = this;?

Comment: Сначала объявите поле класса static TextController; а потом в переопределенном методе @FXML initialize присвойте значение this этому полю, дальше через него уже вызываете методы, меняющие значения в интерфейсе.

Comment: Максим извини я не понял.. Что за поле класса static TextController? В смысле просто объявить эту переменную? Если да, и прописать в Initialize example = this; То пишет что ему требуется в this объект типа Text а нашел он мой контроллер. И вы написали "дальше через него уже вызываете методы" через кого? Вы имеете ввиду использовать этот статик в других потоках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кароче все оказалось намного проще.
Для того чтобы изменить например Text вне контролера,надо передать сам контролер при создании объекта например(Pon4ik pon4ik = new Pon4ik(this)) где в конструкторе ему будет присвоена соответствующая переменная типа(COntroller guiController = pon4ik) и потом уже можно свободно обращаться к переменным контроллера присвоив им public доступ например guiController.TextField.setText("hello"). Не благодарите :))

Answer (score 1):

Создать метод, который должен вызываться для обновления текста

```
public void setText(String text){...
```

В другой поток передать метод, который должен быть вызван для обнволение текста. То есть, в другом классе должно быть что-то вроде.

```
Consumer<String> consumer;

..

public void setOnUpdateText(Consumer<String> consumer){
    this.consumer = cunsumer;
}
```

В момент когда необходимо обновить текст вызывать

```
comsumer.accept("Новый текст");
```

Так же, нельзя изменять содержимое интерфейса из других потоков, кроме потока пользовательского интерфейса. Потому необходимо использовать Platform.runLater();

```
Platform.runLater(() -> { 
    consumer.accept("Новый текст");
});
```

Comment: Уфф. Сложно. Я понял что в момент когда надо изменить текст когда либо надо вызвать Platform.runLater((); Ок. Все остальное прошу пояснить. У нас есть потоки Main, GUI, Other1; запускаются они в таком же порядке(т.к. other по кнопке). В контроллер классе есть private static Text example;(у него же встроенный метод setText есть, который работает из контроллера). Что писать в Other потоке в классе внутри лямбды? попробовал так же через костыль выше в п1. NullPointer получил...

Comment: Я понял что в контроллере должен быть setter. Тогда новый вопрос. Можно ли создавать новый объект класса контроллера?(ну я просто не понимаю кем является для нас контроллер, если мы не создаем его объекта, тогда как мы обратимся к нему по методу setter'y к static переменной из не static class'a?) Даже не так, а как мы получим instance класса контроллера не имея его объекта оО замудрил я)

Comment: И вообще, nullPointer может быть потому, что в контроллере нет инциализации этот Text example. Я так понимаю она идет в fxml

Comment: А откуда потоки Main и Gui? Вродь когда стартуешь Javafx приложение то создается один поток для всего приложения, он же для интерфейса. Я забыл написать передачу метода. Метод необходимо передать. То есть, из контроллера необходимо для потока вызвать еще метод other1.setOnUpdateText(this::setText) при запуске нового потока, либо инициализации. То есть, основная задача это передать другому потоку метод, который он должен вызвать.

Comment: А я толком и незнаю создается ли отдельный поток под GUI,вот теперь понял что нет) А если таких полей около 10-15 штук необходимо передать все? Со static я попутал, там не static.

Comment: Себя запутал и меня запутал. Я уже сам ничего не понимаю) Метод пожно передать один. Один метод update скажем, который будет сам обновлять все нужные поля. Когда поток делает какую-то задачу, он сохраняет какие-то значение и по завершении работы должен вызвать метод update, тем самым дальше должен вступить в работу уже поток пользовательского интерфейса и сам достать все необходимые значения и присвоить их нужным полям. Все сложно :)

Comment: Я ничего не понял.. Извини.. Я не понял что писать в методе setOnUpdateText который должен создаваться в Other. Ведь в нем ничего от контруктора нет.(this нечему прилепить), можно написать там типо Text который он получил example.setText("hello") но кажется ты не это имел ввиду.. Так же не понятно если из конструктора вызвать other1.setOnUpdateText(this::setText) , тогда он ведь вызовет метод, а этот метод должен вызывать поток когда он будет готов обновить данные, если ты не против готов пойти в чат, или вк

Comment: Если речь идет о потоке который должен прекратиться и возвратить значение, то это не так, поток работает рекурсивно через while изменяет параметры в процессе своего выполнения а не в конце

Comment: Я так понял вы предлагаете заглушку что то типа метода который бы был бо доступен и для потока интерфейса и для потока Other в который оба приходят и обмениваются значениям? Если да, тогда как интерфейс узнает когда именно брать ему данные? Через wait? А если интерфейс должен быть активен в этот момент?

Comment: Вариантов на самом деле уйма. И правильного я не знаю     
 public static void update(String text) {
        //example.setText(text);
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    public void onButtonPress() {
  Thread myThread = new Thread() {
  Consumer<String> update = WindowManager::update;

 @Override
 public void run() {
 try {
 while (true) {
Thread.sleep(1000);
 Platform.runLater(() -> {                  update.accept(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
  });
  }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
};
    }

Comment: Ура! кажется мы на верном пути потому что теперь встал вопрос вот тут //example.setText(text); . Это было бы актуально при условии что example - static. Но SceneBuilder создает их private Text(не статик) и example.setText не сработал т.к. выдает NullPointerException(хотя когда я делал тоже самое из потока интерфейса это работало(и делал на время их статик)),но понятно что так делать не нужно, так как же сделать если он не статик, инциализировать? (Я имею ввиду, что мы создали static метод, чтобы таки изменить static переменную которая по умолчанию идет не статик)

Comment: Что нужно? Определить его нужно) Если он определяется через Fxml и на момент вызова кнопки он все еще null, значит ты ошибся где-то в имени компонента, или не дописал @FXML над полем, потому оно не может само установить значение

Comment: Consumer<String> update = WindowManager.this::update; еще так вродь можно, чтобы не статик указывать. Это передаст метод самого котроллера

Comment: WindowManager.this::update; Пишет - is not en enclosing class. Что касается переменной, я сижу в идеи и слева на полях появляется соответствующий значок когда это прикреплено к FXML и когда нет. Так вот когда я делаю private Text example он прикрепляется, когда private static Text example; значок убирается, выше конечно стоит @FXML. В этом вся оставшееся проблема. Мы не можем указать ей статик т.к. статик будет Null. А определяется он только как не static :( И я ошибся. setText со статиком работало только при инциализации.

Comment: Что-то не то делаешь. WindowManager(название не поменял) это должен быть твой контроллер со всеми методами и полями. Тогда пример заработает

Comment: Поменял конечно, иначе бы даже на тест не пропустило горело красным https://ibb.co/bAYT3J (пкм открыть в новом окне)

Comment: Так обновления по setText. Он работает если в кнопке на onAction вызвать example.setText(при условии что example подключен к FXML и соответственно не статик). А это означает, что надо метод сделать не статичным. вы правильно копали, но что то пошло не так

Comment: Эх. Ладно. Разбирайся. Я идею подал)

Comment: Ладно) Спасибо за идею, почти довели до конца, там уже совсем другой вопрос остался)) Думаю мб открыть новую ветку т.к. эту ты по сути на 90% решил))